# cannot get jscrollpane api for dynamic size to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I have been experimenting with [jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to add custom scrollbars to some content. The data is being pulled in via ajax and the [jscrollpane api](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ajax.html) works nicely for that.

But I'm trying to make the scrollpane have a height that is always, say, 70% of the height of the users browser window. The [jscrollpane site](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_height.html) says that I can use the following code to make it work, but i'm having no luck.

```
$(function () {
    $('.scroll-pane').each(

    function () {
        $(this).jScrollPane({
            showArrows: $(this).is('.arrow')
        });
        var api = $(this).data('jsp');
        var throttleTimeout;
        $(window).bind('resize', function () {
            if ($.browser.msie) {
                // IE fires multiple resize events while you are dragging the browser window which
                // causes it to crash if you try to update the scrollpane on every one. So we need
                // to throttle it to fire a maximum of once every 50 milliseconds...
                if (!throttleTimeout) {
                    throttleTimeout = setTimeout(

                    function () {
                        api.reinitialise();
                        throttleTimeout = null;
                    }, 50);
                }
            } else {
                api.reinitialise();
            }
        });
    })

});
```

When I change the css to a percentage, the custom scrollbar fails entirely, and I get a default chrome scrollbar that is 100% of the height of the window.

http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/2yEsG/

Thank you very much!

Comment: this might be a jsfiddle issue actually...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears that there is some compatibility problem with the api for resize and jsfiddle. jscrollpane continues to be an amazing extension. thanks.